# Js if active then input required

Tags: javascript

I have this radio form which make active a specific input type text when the radio is checked. 
I want the input that is active to be required to submit the form but i'm pretty bad in JS right now. If someone could help it would be trully appreciated thx u !

Here is my code :

```
<div class=" bottommargin-sm">
    <label>Platforme<small class="text-danger">*</small> : </label>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle nav" data-toggle="buttons">
        <a href="#attending-tab-1" class="btn btn-outline-youtube px-4 t600 ls0 nott si-youtube flex-fill" data-toggle="tab">
            <input type="radio" name="choice-platform" required value="0"><i class="icon-youtube"></i> Youtube
        </a>
        <a href="#attending-tab-2" class="btn btn-outline-soundcloud px-4 t600 ls0 nott si-soundcloud flex-fill" data-toggle="tab">
            <input type="radio" name="choice-platform" id="template-wedding-attending-no" value="1" required><i class="icon-soundcloud1"></i> Soundcloud
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane bg-light p-4 mt-2" id="attending-tab-1">
            <div class="row">
                <input type="text" name="platform1" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane bg-light p-4 mt-2" id="attending-tab-2">
            <div class="row">
                <input type="text" name="platform2" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish exactly? You question doesn't say what the problem is or what you tried.

Comment: where's the javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to make an HTML form field required based on a user select option. Then hope this will work for you.

```js
function updateRequirement() {
  var form = document.forms[0];
  var radios = document.getElementsByName('option');
  var selectedValue;
  for( i = 0; i < radios.length; i++ ) {
      if( radios[i].checked ) {
        selectedValue = radios[i].value;
      }
  }
  if(selectedValue === 'yes') {
    document.getElementById('non-mandatoryfield').required = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('non-mandatoryfield').required = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  Make optional field mandatory <br />
  <div id="options">
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="yes" onchange="updateRequirement()"> Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="no" onchange="updateRequirement()"> No<br>
  </div>
  <br />
  First name: (Required Always)<br />
  <input type="text" required name="firstname" value="" />
  <br />
  Last name: (Optional Always)<br />
  <input type="text" id="non-mandatoryfield" name="lastname" value="" />
  <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the js code

```
$("#template-wedding-attending-no").on("checked", function () {
    $("#attending-tab-1").prop(true);
})
```

Comment: that is jquery code, not js code. There is no jquery tag on this question so this is an invalid answer